# How to install Maven on OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: java, maven, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install Maven on my Mac, but I can not get the JAVA_HOME variable right. The path that the maven website gives is,

```
usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51
```

however the java folder does not exist in /usr/ for me. I installed the JRE and JDK, nothing changed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed? If so, easiest thing is just `brew install maven`.

Comment: I did that, and when I use mvn --version it says the JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Comment: if it says JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, put the following line on your .bash_profile file `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` , save the file and reload using `source .bash_profile` command

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Installing Maven (for me) usually involves these steps (apart from having a working java installed):

- Download Maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
- Unpack to /path/to/maven

Set the following in .bashrc

```
export M2_HOME=/path/to/maven
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Reload bash, and now "mvn --version" should be fine. Make sure to not have any reference to JAVA_HOME in your .bashrc (or .bash_aliases) if you havent already set it to somewhere you placed your jdk.

Comment: Thanks so much! What got me was the reloadd bash part, I now remember having to do this a long time ago on Windows. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Zach443: You are welcome. Dont forget to accept the answer, to make the problem/question solved.

Comment: Of course, I just had to wait for the time constraint to run out :)

Answer (score 120):

Using brew - `brew install maven` - that's it.

Comment: If you are getting errors with the url, try "brew update" and then "brew install maven"

Comment: That worked for me thx, and I hope because its put into /usr/local it wont be lost next time I do an major version operating system upgrade. But /usr/local/mvn is a symbolic link to ../Cellar/maven/3.3.3/bin/mvn - why/what is Cellar ?

Comment: this works if u are in the later versions of Mac, but below 2012 Mac version

Answer (score 5):

In my case, none of the exported variables saved after bash quit. Also, `export M2=$M2_HOME/bin; export PATH=$M2:$PATH` into bash didn't help, either. So, I had to write absolute paths into bash profile. Here are my steps:

1) open bash

2) next two steps are required to correctly create paths in your system. Type in (line by line)

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
export M2_HOME=/path/to/your/apache-maven-3.x.x
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

3) than echo all four variables

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $M2_HOME
echo $M2
echo $PATH
```

4) open second window of bash for your convenience.

5) choose root folder (type cd without anything and press enter)

```
cd
```

6) if you don’t have file called «.bash_profile» than just create it

```
touch .bash_profile
```

7) open edit your «.bash_profile»

```
nano .bash_profile
```

5) copy results of echo commands to your «.bash_profile». it should look something like.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
M2_HOME=/path/to/your/apache-maven-3.x.x
M2=/path/to/your/apache-maven-3.x.x/bin
PATH=/path/to/your/apache-maven-3.x.x/bin:/path/to/maven/bin:/$….bla-bla-bla…
```

6) after edit save by pressing ctrl+s and close by ctrl+x

Answer (score 3):

For [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) : `sudo port install maven3`

Change maven3 to maven1 or maven2 for corresponding version number.

Answer (score 1):

On Yosemite, I've not had JAVA_HOME defined and I have version '1.7.0_65'. I also have [maven](http://maven.apache.org) installed and use it nearly every day. Installation of maven is performed by the following steps:

1. `curl http://download.nextag.com/apache/maven/maven-3/3.2.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.3-bin.tar.gz | tar pzxvf -`
2. set the `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable to:

`pwd`/apache-maven-3.2.3

3. add MAVEN_HOME to your path.

Now you should be golden. Leave a comment if you aren't sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is late.

I installed JDK and Maven following instructions from each of those sites, then I had to edit my `.profile` file to get the PATH variables set.

```
$ sudo vim .profile
```

Then I added the following to my .profile (`i` for insert mode)

```
# JDK configuration
#
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
#
# Maven configuration
#
MAVEN_3_3_3=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3
export MAVEN_3_3_3
M2_HOME=$MAVEN_3_3_3
export M2_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Next you write and quit vim (`:wq`), quit and reopen terminal and type `mvn --version` to test your install.

Your output should look like this:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T06:57:37-05:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

**Note:** you may need to adjust the paths to your jdk and maven installations.

Comment: Did not work when I edited .profile. I added the above info to `$ nano .bash_profile` and its working now. You probably need to mention where to create that `.profile` file, its possible that I created/edited the wrong one. But I dont know for sure.